# Evaluate: $\; \displaystyle \int e^{-3 x}\cos 6 x \, dx$ Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms, complex-integration

Evaluate: $\; \displaystyle \int e^{-3 x}\cos 6 x \, dx$

Formula to integrate by parts is:

$$ u \cdot v - \int u' \cdot v$$

I'm stuck, here's where I get:

$ u = e^{-3x}, \;\;\;\; du = -3 e^{-3x}$

$ dv = \cos6x, \;\;\;\; v = \frac{\sin6x}{6} $

->

$ e^{-3x} \cdot \frac{\sin6x}{6} - \int -3̶ e^{-3x} \cdot \frac{\sin6x}{6̶} $

2)

$ u = -1 e^{-3x}, \;\;\;\; du = -3 e^{-3x}$

$ dv = \frac{\sin6x}{6}, \;\;\;\; v = - \frac{\cos6x}{6}$

->

$ e^{-3x} \cdot \frac{\sin6x}{6} - (-e^{-3x} \cdot - \frac{\cos6x}{6} - \int -3e^{-3x} \cdot - \frac{\cos6x}{6})$

And on and on it goes, I just can't get rid of e^{-3x}, nor by integrating it nor by differentiating. Perhaps, by integration there's a chance, if I remove power of $e$ somehow.

Anyway, what can I do here?

Comment: Write $J$ for your original integral. Applying integration by parts twice you will find for some constant $k$

$$J = something + k J$$

Now solve for $J$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int e^{-3 x}\cos 6 xdx = e^{-3x} \cdot \frac{\sin6x}{6} - (-e^{-3x} \cdot - \frac{\cos6x}{6} - \int -3e^{-3x} \cdot - \frac{\cos6x}{6}dx) = e^{-3x} \frac{\sin6x}{6} - e^{-3x} \frac{\cos6x}{6} + \int e^{-3x} \frac{\cos6x}{2}dx$

then subtract $\int e^{-3x} \frac{cos6x}{2}dx$ from both sides to get:

$\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-3x}cos6xdx= e^{-3x} \frac{sin6x}{6} - e^{-3x} \frac{cos6x}{6}$

Then multiply through my 2 to get:

$\int e^{-3x}cos6xdx= e^{-3x} \frac{sin6x}{3} - e^{-3x} \frac{cos6x}{3}$

Or

$\int e^{-3x}cos6xdx= \frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}(sin6x- cos6x)$

Answer (score 1):

Clever complex analysis solves this easily, see if you follow:

$\cos x=\Re(e^{ix})$

We'll use this fact and change the integrand to $e^{3x}e^{ix}$.

We'll get,

$$\int e^{(3+i)x}dx=\frac{e^{(3+i)x}}{3+i}=(\frac{3}{10}-\frac{i}{10})e^{3x}e^{ix}=(\frac{3}{10}-\frac{i}{10})e^{3x}(\cos x+ i \sin x)=\frac{3}{10}e^{3x}(\cos x +i \sin x)-\frac{i}{10}e^{3x}(\cos x + i \sin x)+C$$

Taking real parts yields:

$$\frac{3}{10}e^{3x} \cos x+\frac{1}{10} e^{3x} \sin x +C$$

Wolfram Alpha verifies my answer:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%283x%29+cos%28x%29

Hope this helps. I know it isn't the way you wanted but it is still pretty neat.

Comment: This is not the integral asked. Also *we* verify WA, not vice versa ;-)

Comment: @SimonS I suspect you may have been joking about the you verifying WA. I know this is not what is asked, but this method is equally cool and helpful. If you'd like I'll do the other method.

Comment: WA sometimes makes mistakes. But the more serious point is that it is straight forward to confirm this result by carefully checking the logic of your derivation or by differentiating your result; the fact WA agrees with your answer is in an important sense weaker evidence of its correctness than either of those methods. (On evaluating the integral another way: no need, especially since the OPer doesn't appear engaged.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $$I = \int e^{-3x}\cos6x\ \mathrm{d}x$$ Notice that integral is in your last step. Replace it with an $I$ and then solve for $I$.